# How to reduce the .exe size of a program in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe, self-contained

I am trying to make a single file executable in C#. The program does not have alot of code, yet the output is around 50mb even when I am using PublishTrimmed. Is there a way I can decrease the size of this? Thanks.

Configuration: Debug | Any CPU
Target Framework: net core 3.1 (windows)
Target Runtime: win x-64
Deployment Mode: Single File / Self Contained

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/globalization-invariant-mode.md

Comment: never publish programs in debug mode

Comment: Do you need to deploy self-contained? If you use a framework-dependent deployment, your application will be significantly smaller.

Comment: I haven't seen your update in a long time, do you have time to check our answer.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay in my response. My application is only targeting windows and should be 32 bit if this helps answer your question, I don't think I need it to be self contained.

Comment: @catlover1200 Did you try my answer below? If you don't mind and it works, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the configuration to `Release` instead of `Debug`.

You can disable `Self Contained` when the user has the appropriate `.net runtime` installed. This can save a lot of space.

If your `exe` contains resources such as videos, it may not be able to shrink.

`Self Contained` also has many benefits and saves a lot of trouble, you can check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained) for details.

Comment: If  it's already 50MB, you can be fairly confident that 'Self Contained' is disabled already!  My personal experience with 'Publish Trimmed' is that the algorithm wasn't great at walking depndencies and subsequently produced an .exe that wouldn't run due to missing dll's!

Comment: It seems that `self contained` has not been turned off in the current op's information. Just do my best to serve the op.